# Add the placeholder required in swagger ui v2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

i got this swagger description:

```
  APIExperimentProperties:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: "string"
      experimentVariants:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/APIExperimentVariantProperties"
      owner:
        type: "string"
      label:
        type: "string"
      ticketId:
        type: "string"
      featureName:
        type: "string"
```

---

```
  APIExperimentVariantProperties:
    type: object
    required:
    - id
    - name
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      name:
        type: "string"
```

I wanted to make the fields id and name in APIExperimentVariantProperties to be marked as required in the swagger-ui.
[image]
As you can see in the picture, it looks like it worked.
It removed the optional from the field, and their labels are bolder
(the id field vs the featureName field for example).

But I am trying to make their placeholder say that it's required field, just like it did automatically for the field in the image below.
[image]

Any idea how to do that? the decimation didn't give any additional leads.

Comment: The 1st image is the [JSON form editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) integrated in Swagger UI (it's an optional feature in Swagger UI). The 2nd image is Swagger UI's own parameter editor. Hence the difference. You probably need to write some JavaScript that would add the `placeholder` attribute dynamically to the required input fields in the JSON form editor component.

Comment: By the way, your version of Swagger UI, 2.x., is old and no longer maintained. The latest version 3.x ([as seen here](http://petstore.swagger.io)) no longer uses the JSON form editor for JSON body input.

Comment: Thanks! I know about the 2.0 and 3.0, but currently thats the version we are working with #techdebt :)